# Getting requirements to build whell . . . error, when trying install pyaudio

Tags: pyaudio

I trying to install pyaudio by this command: pip install pyaudio
and Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
I'm using laptop, win 10enter code here

C:\Users\Kiet Tran\OneDrive\Documents\python>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [33 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
backend = _build_backend()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 77, in *build_backend
obj = import_module(mod_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1381, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1354, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1381, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1354, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 929, in *load_unlocked
File "", line 994, in exec_module
File "", line 488, in *call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-09lbisw4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init**.py", line 16, in 
import setuptools.version
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-09lbisw4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in 
import pkg_resources
File "C:\Users\Kiet Tran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-09lbisw4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init**.py", line 2191, in 
register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: Perhaps add some formatting like as a quote for error messages to separate from you actual one question/challenge here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean)

Comment: PyAudio has been updated to fix this problem.