# AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Earlier I installed some packages like [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), pip (version 23.3.1), wheel (version 0.41.2), etc., and did some programming with those. I used the command `C:\Users\UserName>pip list` to find the list of packages that I have installed, and I am using Python 3.12.0 (by employing code `C:\Users\UserName>py -V`).

I need to use [pyspedas](https://github.com/spedas/pyspedas) to analyse some data. I am following the instruction that that I received from site to install the package, with a variation (I am not sure whether it matters or not: I am using `py`, instead of `python`). The commands that I use, in the order, are:

```
py -m venv pyspedas
.\pyspedas\Scripts\activate
pip install pyspedas
```

After the last step, I am getting the following output:

```
Collecting pyspedas
  Using cached pyspedas-1.4.47-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.19.5 (from pyspedas)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Collecting requests (from pyspedas)
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting geopack>=1.0.10 (from pyspedas)
  Using cached geopack-1.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting cdflib<1.0.0 (from pyspedas)
  Using cached cdflib-0.4.9-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting cdasws>=1.7.24 (from pyspedas)
  Using cached cdasws-1.7.43.tar.gz (21 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting netCDF4>=1.6.2 (from pyspedas)
  Using cached netCDF4-1.6.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting pywavelets (from pyspedas)
  Using cached PyWavelets-1.4.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\UserName\pyspedas\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\UserName\pyspedas\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\UserName\pyspedas\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\UserName\pyspedas\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_lgbq70y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_lgbq70y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_lgbq70y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2191, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

After little bit of googling, I came to know that this issues was reported at multiple places, but none for this package. I did install wheel in the new environment as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504270/6323020), but the problem still persists.

Instead of setting up a virtual environment, I simply executed the command `py -m pip install pyspedas`. But I am still getting the error.

What I could gather is that the program has an issue with

```
Collecting pywavelets (from pyspedas)
  Using cached PyWavelets-1.4.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
```

I am using [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) in Windows 11.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

#### If you can downgrade to Python 3.11 then you will probably not face any issue.

---

##### If you must use only Python 3.12, then here is an attempt to solve the issue:

---

> AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

occurs due to using Python 3.12.

Due to the removal of the long-deprecated pkgutil.ImpImporter class, the pip command may not work for Python 3.12.

Here is the link to a post which describes it: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/10/fix-broken-pip-python-312-ubuntu/

**You just have to manually install pip for Python 3.12**

There are a couple of methods to fix this. In your virtual environment:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

**Task 1:**

Python comes with an `ensurepip`, which can install pip in a Python environment.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

On **Linux/macOS** terminal:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

On **Windows**:

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

**Task 2:**

You need to install the [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) package via:

```
python -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

If it is already present then:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Then create a new virtual environment by:

```
virtualenv your_virtual_environment --python=python3.12
```

Activate `your_virtual_environment` and you will be ready to install packages.

*Other points to note*:

`virtualenv` likes to cache packages to save on loading up environments, including caching old versions of pip

You may have an old cached version of pip in your computer.

You may need to run:

```
virtualenv --upgrade-embed-wheels
```

and

```
virtualenv --reset-app-data <path_to_your_venv>
```

Better upgrade `setuptools` as well:

```
python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

https://pythontest.com/posts/2023/2023-10-02-py312-impimporter/

---

Quote from: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/pull/10844

> Having an outdated version of pip is still the main problem, but the outdated version of pip didn't come from the python installation, but from the virtualenv creation.
>
> When creating the environment, virtualenv installs some specfic/outdated [sic] versions of pip/setuptools/wheels.

[virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/20.7.2/src/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/__init__.py)

---

Related gits:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11501

https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/2342

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12179

https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/10832

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3935

https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-python/issues/1824

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I executed the commands
`C:\Users\UserName>pip -V` & `C:\Users\UserName>py -m ensurepip --upgrade`, whose response was
`pip 23.3.1 from C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)`
and 
`Looking in links: c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp23bccewt
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (23.3.1).`
But the problem still persists.

Comment: Thnx for the quick reply. But still no. The commands I executed are `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`, `py -m pip` and `py -m pip install pyspedas` (I didn't use `py -m venv pyspedas`). Further, space shouldn't be there `-- upgrade`? It was creating an error for me.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate all your help. I executed the commands in the following order: `pip install --upgrade virtualenv` --> `virtualenv venv123 --python=python3.12` --> `venv123\Scripts\activate.bat` --> `pip install pyspedas`. But still persists.
Do you think that installing an older version will solve the issue?

Comment: python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools solved it for me, Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: how is python still so broken? i spend 90% of my time chasing down stuff like this in any one of the 15 package managers supposedly there ot make my life easier. Just an awful experience trying to use any of this freeware garbage

Comment: Adding `setuptools` to the `Pipfile` seemed to fix this on one occasion.

Answer (score 7):

Python has removed some previously deprecated symbols in the `importlib`. This is mentioned in the [Python 3.12 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#importlib)

> Many previously deprecated cleanups in importlib have now been completed:
>
> ...
>
> - `importlib.abc.Finder`, `pkgutil.ImpImporter`, and `pkgutil.ImpLoader` have been removed. (Contributed by Barry Warsaw in [gh-98040](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98040).)

The error message means that something tries to use the removed `pkgutil.ImpImporter` during package install. This something may be either pip, setuptools, or the `setup.py` install script in the package itself. Looking at the stacktrace, upgrading `setuptools` (inside virtual environment if you use virtual environment) should fix this.

Also note this related release notes entry in 3.12

> [gh-95299](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95299): Do not pre-install setuptools in virtual environments created with venv. This means that distutils, setuptools, pkg_resources, and easy_install will no longer available by default; to access these run `pip install setuptools` in the activated virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

What did work for me on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish) was installing the development header files for Python 3.12.

```bash
sudo apt install python3.12-dev
```

After that, everything went well.

Everything else didn't work for me, because upgrading any package on existing Python 3.12 virtual environment would result into the same error. After installing the `python3.12-dev` both `pip` and `setuptools` were fresh.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented the issue is python 3.12 being incompatible with the version of pip.

My initial solution was:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
pip3.12 install ...
```

where ... was the package wanting to be installed.

This was an incomplete solution as my IDE (pycharm) was still throwing the same error opening other files.

The below code upgraded the pip version globally:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I then followed this with refreshing my IDE. This is currently working.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was listing older version of NumPy in requirements.txt, which may be obvious problem, but for people stuck with this:

Check for the [newer versions of NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/). I needed to list it as:

```
numpy~=1.26.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue as I only just installed 3.12 on a venv and encountered the issue. Some of the suggestions above worked for me. For information I'm using Windows and Pycharm for my development.

Every time I tried to install a package on this fresh 3.12 installation I got the same attribute error. To fix it I did the following.

from the terminal inside pycharm:

```bash
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
python -m pip install <module>
```

One thing I've noticed over previous versions is that at least on however mine is setup the `python -m` as a prefix to pip is now mandatory, whereas before I could just go straight to a `pip install <module>` command. This may be down to something different in my setup or it could be due to a force from 3.12...

While the answers that got me working are above. I'm putting this in just in case anyone on a similar setup to me is encountering the issue and this may give them the quick solution as opposed to trial and error to get there.

Thank you to the previous posters.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue as I only just installed 3.12. This solution worked for me. Because I have an old version of pandas in the dependencies package, I only had to update the Pandas version because it was not compatible with Python 3.12, and everything worked smoothly