# Note:AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
pip install pyaudio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import Distribution
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

Also `pipwin install pyaudio` shows error

```
pipwin: The term 'pipwin' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

**Please help me fix this. I tried everything I could. No progress done**

I just want to Install py audio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is the pip --version

Comment: @wim that shows pip 23.3.1

Comment: Something is broken with your installation. Line 2164 of `_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py` is not like that, it's [like this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/23.3.1/src/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2164). The actual use of `ImpImporter` in 23.3.1 tag is guarded with an attribute check [like this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/23.3.1/src/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2231-L2232). Recommend to uninstall/reinstall pip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean)

Comment: PyAudio has been updated to fix this problem.