# Python " AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'? "

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I need to compile the .py to .exe with pyinstaller and i always catch this error:

> ```
> 198, in _run_module_as_main File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in
> _run_code File "D:\Program Files\python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
> File "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 214, in
> _console_script_run run() File "D:\Program Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 170, in
> run parser = generate_parser()
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Program Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 136, in
> generate_parser import PyInstaller.building.build_main File
> "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
> line 28, in <module> from PyInstaller.building.api import COLLECT,
> EXE, MERGE, PYZ File "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 32,
> in <module> from PyInstaller.building.splash import Splash  # argument
> type validation in EXE
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Program Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\splash.py", line
> 23, in <module> from PyInstaller.depend import bindepend File
> "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line
> 25, in <module> from PyInstaller.depend import dylib, utils File
> "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 31,
> in <module> from PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph import modulegraph File
> "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
> line 34, in <module> from altgraph.ObjectGraph import ObjectGraph File
> "D:\Program Files\python\Lib\site-packages\altgraph\__init__.py", line
> 142, in <module> import pkg_resources File "D:\Program
> Files\python\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2191,
> in <module> register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
> ```

I created simple file with

```
print("Hello world")
```

I tried to go to dir with programm

> ~\Scripts\Python\Simple programm\

Comment: See: [AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean)