# Environment not building on pipeline after not changes that would effect the build process

Tags: python, docker, azure-pipelines

I have made some minor updates to a python application I'm working on, nothing that requires new dependencies and I have tested this by branching up a previous a commit that was successfully built on the same pipeline and it still failed. So I believe something has changed within docker to cause this and I have no idea what it is.

Little background around my changes was that i changed some logic around how i was grabbing data in pandas and added a filter around some warnings, that was really it, did not require any new packages to complete this task.

This is my docker file which I have redacted the env variables for due to them being very private :

```
FROM python:3.9.13 AS compile-image

LABEL Name=paddybot Version=0.1
EXPOSE 80

#Run environment updates and installs
RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install build-essential -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    libpq-dev 

#Miniconda
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh &&\
     /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN conda config --set restore_free_channel true

#Run requirments install
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV client_id {secrets}
ENV client_secret {secrets}
ENV market_id {secrets}
ENV tenant_id {secrets}
ENV vault_url {secrets}

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Here is my build YAML:

```
    trigger:
    - main

    resources:
    - repo: self

    variables:
       # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
       dockerRegistryServiceConnection: {secret}
       imageRepository: 'paddybot'
       containerRegistry: {secret}
       dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
       tag: 'latest'
       vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

   stages:
   - stage: Build
   displayName: Build Bot
   jobs:
   - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
```

Here is my requirements file - Note i recently changed catboost from v1.2.2 to 1.2.3 as i thought maybe catboost could of been the issue at first:

```
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-identity==1.13.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-mgmt-resource==22.0.0
msrestazure==0.6.4
azure-storage-blob==12.18.3
catboost==1.2.3
docker==6.1.3
hmmlearn==0.3.0
hyperopt==0.2.5
ipython==8.12.3
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==8.0.4
joblib==1.2.0
json5==0.9.6
jsonpickle==3.0.1
jsonschema==4.17.3
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==7.1.2
jupyter-console==6.4.3
jupyter_core==5.4.0
jupyter-server==1.13.5
jupyterlab==3.3.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-server==2.10.3
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.5
jupyterthemes==0.20.0
keras==2.13.1
keras2onnx==1.6.0
lightgbm==4.1.0
matplotlib
notebook==6.5.4
notebook_shim==0.2.2
numpy==1.24.4
oandapyV20==0.7.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
optuna==3.2.0
pandas==1.1.5
pandas-ta==0.3.14b0
pickle4==0.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.5
plotly==5.17.0
ply==3.11
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
scikit-learn==1.3.2
scikit-plot==0.3.7
seaborn==0.12.2
sklearn-pandas==1.7.0
statsmodels
ta==0.10.2
tblib==2.0.0
urllib3==1.26.8
xgboost==1.7.5
```

Here is my the error im seeing after running the pipeline :

```
##[error]#7 9.035 Installing base environment...
##[error]#7 9.035 
##[error]#7 10.21 
##[error]#7 10.21 Downloading and Extracting Packages: ...working... done
##[error]#7 10.21 
##[error]#7 10.21 Downloading and Extracting Packages: ...working... done
##[error]done
##[error]done
##[error]#7 15.34 installation finished.
##[error]#7 DONE 15.6s
##[error]#8 [4/9] RUN pip install --upgrade pip
##[error]#8 0.776 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages (23.3.1)
##[error]#8 0.922 Collecting pip
##[error]#8 0.991   Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
##[error]#8 1.013 Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
##[error]#8 1.365 Installing collected packages: pip
##[error]#8 1.365   Attempting uninstall: pip
##[error]#8 1.383     Found existing installation: pip 23.3.1
##[error]#8 1.386     Uninstalling pip-23.3.1:
##[error]#8 1.416       Successfully uninstalled pip-23.3.1
##[error]#8 3.086 Successfully installed pip-24.0
##[error]#8 3.086 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
##[error]#8 DONE 3.6s
##[error]#9 [5/9] RUN conda config --set restore_free_channel true
##[error]#9 DONE 0.8s
##[error]#10 [6/9] COPY requirements.txt .
##[error]#10 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#11 [7/9] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
##[error]#11 0.944 Collecting azure-common==1.1.28 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
##[error]#11 1.004   Downloading azure_common-1.1.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.0 kB)
##[error]#11 1.050 Collecting azure-identity==1.13.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
##[error]#11 1.057   Downloading azure_identity-1.13.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (67 kB)
##[error]#11 1.082      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 67.1/67.1 kB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
##[error]#11 1.114 Collecting azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
##[error]#11 1.120   Downloading azure_keyvault_secrets-4.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (28 kB)
##[error]#11 1.173 Collecting azure-mgmt-resource==22.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
##[error]#11 1.194   Downloading azure_mgmt_resource-22.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (30 kB)
##[error]#11 1.238 Collecting msrestazure==0.6.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
##[error]#11 1.245   Downloading msrestazure-0.6.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
##[error]#11 1.294 Collecting azure-storage-blob==12.18.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
##[error]#11 1.300   Downloading azure_storage_blob-12.18.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (26 kB)
##[error]#11 1.451 Collecting catboost==1.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
##[error]#11 1.459   Downloading catboost-1.2.3-cp312-cp312-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
##[error]#11 1.509 Collecting docker==6.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
##[error]#11 1.547   Downloading docker-6.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
##[error]#11 1.587 Collecting hmmlearn==0.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
##[error]#11 1.595   Downloading hmmlearn-0.3.0.tar.gz (77 kB)
##[error]#11 1.606      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.9/77.9 kB 8.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
##[error]#11 1.630   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
##[error]#11 4.626   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

##[error]#11 4.654 Collecting hyperopt==0.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
##[error]#11 4.750   Downloading hyperopt-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
##[error]#11 4.832 Collecting ipython==8.12.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
##[error]#11 4.838   Downloading ipython-8.12.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
##[error]#11 4.868 Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
##[error]#11 4.875   Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
##[error]#11 4.931 Collecting ipywidgets==8.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
##[error]#11 4.938   Downloading ipywidgets-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
##[error]#11 4.984 Collecting joblib==1.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
##[error]#11 5.000   Downloading joblib-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
##[error]#11 5.035 Collecting json5==0.9.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
##[error]#11 5.043   Downloading json5-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
##[error]#11 5.082 Collecting jsonpickle==3.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
##[error]#11 5.090   Downloading jsonpickle-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.5 kB)
##[error]#11 5.146 Collecting jsonschema==4.17.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
##[error]#11 5.162   Downloading jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
##[error]#11 5.197 Collecting jupyter==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
##[error]#11 5.205   Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
##[error]#11 5.267 Collecting jupyter-client==7.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
##[error]#11 5.274   Downloading jupyter_client-7.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
##[error]#11 5.308 Collecting jupyter-console==6.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
##[error]#11 5.317   Downloading jupyter_console-6.4.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
##[error]#11 5.364 Collecting jupyter_core==5.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
##[error]#11 5.372   Downloading jupyter_core-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
##[error]#11 5.458 Collecting jupyter-server==1.13.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
##[error]#11 5.477   Downloading jupyter_server-1.13.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
##[error]#11 5.678 Collecting jupyterlab==3.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
##[error]#11 5.687   Downloading jupyterlab-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
##[error]#11 5.716 Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
##[error]#11 5.727   Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (329 bytes)
##[error]#11 5.797 Collecting jupyterlab-server==2.10.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
##[error]#11 5.805   Downloading jupyterlab_server-2.10.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
##[error]#11 5.851 Collecting jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
##[error]#11 5.860   Downloading jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
##[error]#11 5.911 Collecting jupyterthemes==0.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 27))
##[error]#11 5.920   Downloading jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.0 MB)
##[error]#11 6.196 Collecting keras==2.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
##[error]#11 6.203   Downloading keras-2.13.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
##[error]#11 6.308 Collecting keras2onnx==1.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
##[error]#11 6.317   Downloading keras2onnx-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (219 kB)
##[error]#11 6.327      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 219.8/219.8 kB 32.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
##[error]#11 6.368 Collecting lightgbm==4.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
##[error]#11 6.376   Downloading lightgbm-4.1.0-py3-none-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
##[error]#11 6.559 Collecting matplotlib (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
##[error]#11 6.634 Collecting notebook==6.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
##[error]#11 6.719   Downloading notebook-6.5.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
##[error]#11 6.751 Collecting notebook_shim==0.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 33))
##[error]#11 6.758   Downloading notebook_shim-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
##[error]#11 6.993 Collecting numpy==1.24.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34))
##[error]#11 7.006   Downloading numpy-1.24.4.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
##[error]#11 8.246   Installing build dependencies: started
##[error]#11 11.71   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
##[error]#11 11.72   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
##[error]#11 11.90   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
##[error]#11 11.90   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
##[error]#11 11.90   
##[error]#11 11.90   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
##[error]#11 11.90   │ exit code: 1
##[error]#11 11.90   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
##[error]#11 11.90       Traceback (most recent call last):
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>

##[error]#11 11.90           main()
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
##[error]#11 11.90           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
##[error]#11 11.90                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
##[error]#11 11.90           backend = _build_backend()
##[error]#11 11.90                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
##[error]#11 11.90           obj = import_module(mod_path)
##[error]#11 11.90                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
##[error]#11 11.90           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
##[error]#11 11.90                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
##[error]#11 11.90         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hivx3npt/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
##[error]#11 11.90           import setuptools.version
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hivx3npt/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
##[error]#11 11.90           import pkg_resources
##[error]#11 11.90         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hivx3npt/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
##[error]#11 11.90           register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
##[error]#11 11.90                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##[error]#11 11.90       AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
##[error]#11 11.90       [end of output]
##[error]#11 11.90   
##[error]#11 11.90   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
##[error]#11 11.91 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
##[error]#11 11.91 
##[error]#11 11.91 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
##[error]#11 11.91 │ exit code: 1
##[error]#11 11.91 ╰─> See above for output.
##[error]#11 11.91 
##[error]#11 11.91 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
##[error]#11 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
##[error]------
##[error] > [7/9] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
##[error]11.90       [end of output]
##[error]11.90   
##[error]11.90   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
##[error]11.91 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
##[error]11.91 
##[error]11.91 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
##[error]11.91 │ exit code: 1
##[error]11.91 ╰─> See above for output.
##[error]11.91 
##[error]11.91 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
##[error]------
##[error]Dockerfile:31
##[error]--------------------
##[error]  29 |     #Run requirments install
##[error]  30 |     COPY requirements.txt .
##[error]  31 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
##[error]  32 |     
##[error]  33 |     ENV client_id 334ad5b6-537d-408f-a089-cee496a50532
##[error]--------------------
##[error]ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: [AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean)

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher I upgraded the python version from 3.9.13 > 3.11 but the same error occurs. I will edit my post as i did accidently leave out the python version from the docker file.

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher I have also upgraded it to 3.12, added the command 'pip install --upgrade setuptools' and defined my ubuntu version = 22.04 but none of that helped and the issue persisted

Comment: I'm seeing `numpy==1.24.4` under 'Here is my the error im seeing after running the pipeline' and that is where it goes off the rails which makes sense because right below that it in the error output shows `python3.12` and [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.24.4-notes.html) says "The Python versions supported by this release are 3.8-3.11.".

Comment: @Wayne great observation, maybe I'm accidentally running multiple versions of python somewhere, il investigate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve this problem thanks to comments.

Even though I am defining a version for python here

```
FROM python:3.9.13 AS compile-image
```

when installing MiniConda from this line

```
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh &&\
 /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
```

This automatically downloads python version 3.12/latest and the current version of numpy I am using as shown in the comments can only be used for version 3.8-3.11

I has change my code to this

```
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_23.11.0-2-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh &&\
/bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
```

this would then use Py version 3.9 when downloading Miniconda and successfully building