No module named 'pyttsx3'
Iam trying to set my project with pyttsx3. Doing project to school (my final). I wrote simple code, I also tried code from chat gpt and advices from internet. Working in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 . But my problem is that idea is saying "import pyttsx3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'"
I checked powershell where I do have modul written so should be installed. Please note that Iam really begginer but I really do want to learn that, but idk here Iam stuck
sdk check
part of the code with error message
Speech classenter code here
There is try to install pyttsx3 directly to project. After instalation its saying same error terminal
-Tried to pip and pip3 again those libraries
-Tried to define sdk in project structure
-Tried to do it in the project settings, but Iam not seeing python library part in it
-Restarted project, program and pc
-powershell is saying that everything is installed
powershell check

You've installed the module in the base python , but the Pycharm is executing your code in the virtual enviroment, so it is trying to get the module from there.
Install the module in the Pycharm terminal (alt+f12) (with your project opened), it will install directly in the virtual enviroment.

Okay, I did opened terminal in my project in the idea. Wrote install "pip install pyttxsx3 SpeechRecognition" and it didnt help. I added screen from terminal higher.

Tried to install both packages here (Python 3.10) and it works. Try to downgrade your python as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean

The error originated from speech.py but the image you posted is of chatbot.py.
There is most likely nothing wrong with the code but the compiler for some reason can't find the required module.
