nox unexpected behaviour when switching between python 3.6 and 3.12
I built a Pyenv image using a Dockerfile that contains the following lines (showing only relevant lines):
...
# Install Python versions
RUN pyenv install 3.6
RUN pyenv install 3.12
RUN pyenv global 3.12 3.6 && pyenv rehash

# Upgrade pip for all versions
RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3.12 install --upgrade pip
...

I have a noxfile.py containing the following:
...
python_versions=["3.6", "3.12"]

nox.options.sessions = ['tests']

@nox.session(python=python_versions)
def tests(session):
    session.install('.[dev]')
    junitxml_path = f'reports/unittests/py{session.python}_junit.xml'
    junit_suite = f'py{session.python}'
    session.run('pytest', 'alltests', '--junitxml=' + junitxml_path, '-o', 'junit_suite_name=' + junit_suite)


and I run nox via this Dockerfile:
FROM myregistry/pyenv:v3.12.0.0

RUN pyenv versions

# Requirements used by noxfile
RUN pip install nox pydantic ruamel.yaml

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["nox"]
CMD []


I get this error for version 3.6:
nox > Running session tests-3.6
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.6 in .nox/tests-3-6
nox > Command /root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.3/bin/python3.12 -m virtualenv /app/.nox/tests-3-6 -p python3.6 failed with exit code 1:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.6'
nox > Session tests-3.6 failed.

however version 3.12 installs successfully:
nox > Running session tests-3.12
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.12 in .nox/tests-3-12
nox > python -m pip install '.[dev]'
nox > pytest tt/tests --junitxml=reports/unittests/py3.12_junit.xml -o junit_suite_name=py3.12
...


So I go back to my Pyenv image and rebuild it after swapping round the versions in the RUN pyenv global line so the new line looks like this:
RUN pyenv global 3.6 3.12 && pyenv rehash

Now when I run nox again, version 3.6 installs successfully
nox > Running session tests-3.6
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.6 in .nox/tests-3-6
nox > python -m pip install '.[dev]'
nox > pytest tt/tests --junitxml=reports/unittests/py3.6_junit.xml -o junit_suite_name=py3.6
...

but 3.12 fails with these errors:
nox > Running session tests-3.12
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.12 in .nox/tests-3-12
nox > python -m pip install '.[dev]'
nox > Command python -m pip install '.[dev]' failed with exit code 1:
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 179, in handle_pip_version_check
    session = self._build_session(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/app/.nox/tests-3-12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
nox > Session tests-3.12 failed.

Can anyone explain what's going on (and how to fix it) please?

How does your application use two different Python versions at the same time?  Can you build your image FROM python:3.12, and skip using pyenv here?  Python 3.6 is so old that it seems to have stopped getting security updates, is it possible that pyenv just can't install it?

Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77364550/407651

@mzjn Thank you, that does explain the 3.12 error.

@DavidMaze: it doesn't use two versions at the same time. It installs one version, runs tests, then installs the next version and runs the same tests again; the idea is to test for compatibility with different versions.
