Can't install espnet, error with pkgutil.IMpImporter
My python is version 3.12.3 and my pip is currently up to date. I've tried a bunch of fixes involving updating pip and python but nothing seems to be working? Any help would be appreciated, also I'm kinda new to this so if this is a dumb mistake I apologize. If anyone has recommendations for other tts that are easier to install I'm also more than willing to take suggestions.
C:\Users\wizne>pip install espnet
Collecting espnet
  Using cached espnet-202402-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (68 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=38.5.1 in c:\users\wizne\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from espnet) (70.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\wizne\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from espnet) (24.0)
Collecting configargparse>=1.2.1 (from espnet)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
Collecting typeguard==2.13.3 (from espnet)
  Using cached typeguard-2.13.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting humanfriendly (from espnet)
  Using cached humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.4.1 (from espnet)
  Using cached scipy-1.13.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\wizne\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from espnet) (3.13.1)
Collecting librosa==0.9.2 (from espnet)
  Using cached librosa-0.9.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.2 kB)
Collecting jamo==0.4.1 (from espnet)
  Using cached jamo-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting PyYAML>=5.1.2 (from espnet)
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: soundfile>=0.10.2 in c:\users\wizne\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from espnet) (0.12.1)
Collecting h5py>=2.10.0 (from espnet)
  Using cached h5py-3.11.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting kaldiio>=2.18.0 (from espnet)
  Using cached kaldiio-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.11.0 in c:\users\wizne\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from espnet) (2.3.0+cu121)
Collecting torch-complex (from espnet)
  Using cached torch_complex-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting nltk>=3.4.5 (from espnet)
  Using cached nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.24 (from espnet)
  Using cached numpy-1.23.5.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d78khjsy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d78khjsy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Users\wizne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d78khjsy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.```


https://stackoverflow.com/a/77364602/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+pkgutil+has+no+attribute+ImpImporter

I tried that solution thats linked but it still gives me the same error

maybe it doesn't work with Python 3.12 and you may have to use older Python. You could also find page with source code for espnet and check how old it is. And maybe page has information what version of Python it supports.

page espnet shows it was tested only with Python 3.10 (and olders) - so you may have to install Python 3.10 to use it.
