Setuptools unable to read requirements.txt from pyproject.toml in python 3.12.x
I have a package structure as follows:
program_root/
    - src/
    - tests/ 
    - data/
        - templates/
    - docs/         
    - pyproject.toml        
    - README
    - requirements.txt

My pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools==62.6.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.*"]

[project]
name = "file_ops"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = [
  {name="abc", email="abc@xyz.com" },
]
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}

when I am trying to build the package, I keep getting the error.
I am getting the following error:
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
The reason why I specifically used the setuptools version 62.6.0 is that it's the version in which setuptools introduced file attribute as following:
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}

Now , when I have gone through the release notes of py 3.12, I got to know that ImpImporter is deprecated.
So, Using some other versions of setuptools gives one of the following errors:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte 

Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist

I am clueless on what version of setuptools should I use now to build the package successfully.
This setuptools history (2nd Point) says that few fields are still in beta. how to know what are they exactly?
Please help me understand if I am doing anything wrong here.
BTW, I am strongly inclined to use only toml file for my packaging needs.
All of the traceback for my first error:
* Creating isolated environment: venv+pip...
* Installing packages in isolated environment:
  - setuptools==62.6.0
  - wheel
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\VAMSI-vectra\Vectra_work\jsonMerging\shared_libraries\vct_file_ops_root\venv_file_ops\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 373, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\VAMSI-vectra\Vectra_work\jsonMerging\shared_libraries\vct_file_ops_root\venv_file_ops\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 357, in main        
    json_out["return_val"] = hook(**hook_input["kwargs"])
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VAMSI-vectra\Vectra_work\jsonMerging\shared_libraries\vct_file_ops_root\venv_file_ops\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 302, in get_requires
_for_build_sdist
    backend = _build_backend()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VAMSI-vectra\Vectra_work\jsonMerging\shared_libraries\vct_file_ops_root\venv_file_ops\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 70, in _build_backen
d
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vectra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Vectra\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kr3vu6_o\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>

    import setuptools.version
  File "C:\Users\Vectra\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kr3vu6_o\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>  
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\Vectra\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kr3vu6_o\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2191, in <mo
dule>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
(venv_file_ops) PS D:\VAMSI-vectra\Vectra_work\jsonMerging\shared_libraries\vct_file_ops_root

Few resources that helped me while I am trying to resolve:

installing setup tools, wheel in venv. But, https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#ensurepip says that in pip > 22.x no need of such explicit installation

Refer to this SOQ: How to reference a requirements.txt in the pyproject.toml of a setuptools project? pointing to requirements.txt is introduced in version 62.6.0
Some features are still in beta version https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v68-1-0

Version of setuptools that introduced mentioning 'file' in dependencies https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v62.6.0/CHANGES.rst#v6260
When I used the same version in the [build-system] table, I was getting ImpImporter is unavailable --issue is incompatibiltiy of setuptools v67.6.0 with Py 3.12 because ImpImporter is deprecated in 3.12 -- refer to this release note :
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#importlib

Setuptools release history notes https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html


Edit:
I got to understand from the inputs of @9769953 that the issue is with encoding of my windows system.
Having an UTF-8 encoded requirements file solved the issue. Now, the issue is configuring the pip freeze > requriements.txt command to ensure that it writes the file in UTF-8 (Not sure if that's possible) OR Modifying the Default encoding of my PC to UTF-8

Did you search for the error? Here's the first hit I got: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean

@9769953 I did try upgrading the pip. but no use.
Couldn't paste my traceback due to character limit. Any other way?

According to the issues at https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3935 , this was solved in setuptools 66.1. I justed your setup, and with 62.6.0 and 66.0 I can reproduce your error. With setuptools 66.1, I have no problems.

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte ": this error would have occurred if you would have had no problems with 62.6 as well; it's not likely to be a setuptools specific problem. Since you're on Windows, and this mentions UTF-8, I'm willing to hazard a guess that your Windows or editor encoding is Latin-1 or something, and not UTF-8.

@9769953, I did try just now with 66.1.0 but sorry, issue still persists. and you are right, now I am getting:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Yes, so the issue does not persist, you're just getting another error. AboutwWhich see also my previous comment. Or are you really getting two errors at once: the pkgutil error and the unicode error?

For PyCharm, under settings -> Editor, check the "File Encodings" settings, then see if both Global and Project encoding are UTF-8 ("System Default: UTF-8" should also be fine). If they're different than UTF-8, that's the cause of your encoding problem.

The warning is just that, a warning: you're using configurations that are still in beta. It'll be probably work fine for you, but if  you use it for anything older than Python 3.12, it may not.

@9769953 Nope, I tried everything you've mentioned:
Initially, Global and project encodings were different. I've ensured both of them are UTF-8.

@9769953 I've made the Default encoding for properties file (at Editor -> File Encoding) to be UTF-8
and also Default Encoding at Editor -> General -> Console to be UTF-8

And you (re)saved the various files? Same error still?

@9769953 Yes I did resave the files and restarted PyCharm as well (just in case, for changes to be applied). But getting the same error.

@9769953 new:
I tried to do this in VS code:
I have requirements file opened and at the bottom, in blue bar, it says that the file is UTF-16LE I clicked on it and it gave two options, ReOpen with Encoding and Save with encoding. I've done :
reopen with encoding and made it to UTF-8. Then my file got some unusual structure with all characters being separated by NULL and  two ? characters at the beginning.
now, when I build,I got:
setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier     ��build==1.2.1

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Could you add the full traceback for the unicode error as well? (Note that your original problem has been solved; this is actually a second question).

@9769953, to meet SO conventions of not having long discussion in comments, I request you to continue the discussion in chat. Also,I've added additional details you requested there in that chat.

No, no chat. Please amend your question with the relevant details, not in comments or chat. You can remove comments that are not relevant anymore.

@9769953 Sure, Checkout the edit.

pip freeze > requriements.txt: where are you running this command?

@9769953 in the terminal of my IDE (PyCharm)

@9769953 BTW, using pip freeze | python -c "import sys, codecs; sys.stdout = codecs.open('requirements.txt', 'w', 'utf-8'); print(sys.stdin.read())" 
I am able to resolve the issue. Appreciate any alternatives.

Check your terminal's locale with locale; see if that shows it to be UTF-8.

@9769953 I've checked output encoding of my (powershell) terminal using [console]::OutputEncoding I got IBM437 as the Body Name and Encoding name as OEM United States.

Powershell terminal; but you're running pip freeze in the PyCharm terminal?

@9769953 Yeah. In PyCharm I've configured C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe as the terminal path. Isn't pip freeze supposed to be run in Power shell?

Any shell / terminal that handles it is fine. But yeah, that encoding could be a likely cause. I'm not familiar how to change the encoding for PowerShell. Possibly, it follows the setting of the OS; you might want to look into that (changing that might require a restart of PyCharm, or a full reboot).

@9769953 yeah will check it out how to do that in ps. Btw, out of curiosity, do you see any issue of any sort at high level if I use the one that I mentioned above?           Because, I feel it’s better to use it / set some automated way of using utf 8 within pycharm terminal rather than messing with the things at OS level

From the inputs of @9769953, I am able to understand the issue.
While generating requirements file with the command pip freeze > requirements.txt, the file is being encoded in UTF-16 LE (In your case, it might be different). so, if the encoding is not UTF-8, chances are that it might be the root cause.
I have manually copied my requirements file into Notepad and in Encoding Tab, I have selected UTF-8 ->saved and moved the file to actual location (location where the requirements file is supposed to be) and then the issue resolved.
So, to programmatically configure the encoding of pip freeze command, I've used the following:
python pip freeze | python -c "import sys, codecs; sys.stdout = codecs.open('requirements.txt', 'w', 'utf-8'); print(sys.stdin.read())" 
